# Symfony 4.4 security get user with relation entity data after login

Tags: php, symfony, security, symfony4

I'm using the security bundle for Symfony 4.4.

My "User" entity is related to the "Info" entity on OneToOne.

When I'm logged I want to have "Info" data without extra query.

for exemple in my controller (after login)

when I use `$this->getUser();`

I have

```php
App\Entity\User\User {#1705 ▼
  -id: 1
  -email: "email@email.com"
  -roles: array:1 [▶]
  -password: "password"
  -info: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\User\Info {#1716 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: false
    -id: 1
    -firstname: null
    -lastname: null
  }
}
```

Expected result

```php
App\Entity\User\User {#1705 ▼
  -id: 1
  -email: "email@email.com"
  -roles: array:1 [▶]
  -password: "password"
  -info: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\User\Info {#1716 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: true
    -id: 1
    -firstname: "Firstname"
    -lastname: "Lastname"
  }
}
```

In my guard

in `getUser` method of my guard I'm using `UserRepository` for find my user by email.

```php
// \App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator


    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        // Load / create our user however you need.
        // You can do this by calling the user provider, or with custom logic here.
        $user = $this->userRepository->findUserByEmail($credentials['email']);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('User not found');
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

```php
// \App\Repository\User\UserRepository

    public function findUserByEmail(string $email): ?User
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
                    ->addSelect('user_info')
                    ->leftJoin('user.info', 'user_info')
                    ->andWhere('user.email = :email')
                    ->setParameter('email', $email)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getOneOrNullResult()
            ;
    }
```

but I'm loosing the entity `Info` data after my login.

How to keep my relation entity data after login ?

Comment: You will need to plug in a custom UserProvider as well.  The UserProvider is what is used to refresh the user each time come back as a logged in user.  By the way, deleting a question and then reposting what is almost the same question is something that is frowned upon.

Comment: Ok i'm creating a custom UserProvider and is working fine.

And sorry for repost I don't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very good question I find because it's really often met by beginners. The link between a custom provider and the getUser() method is not always obvious.
Often the user is not alone in an application, he comes with an address, a team, a size, a color, a packet of information that it is useful to have on hand everywhere without making additional requests.

This link is for Symfony 4.x
https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/custom_provider.html

This link can be usefull for Synfony 5.x
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and if someone always look for an easy solution.

Make you repository implementing the `UserProviderInterface`, add the 3 required methods (`loadUserByUsername`, `refreshUser` & `supportsClass`), modify the `loadUserByUsername` method to join the wanted Doctrine relations and modify security.yaml to use your UserRepository as a custom provider.

```
# src/Repository/UserRepository.php

<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User as UserEntity;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordUpgraderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

/**
 * @method null|UserEntity find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method null|UserEntity findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method UserEntity[]    findAll()
 * @method UserEntity[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements PasswordUpgraderInterface, UserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * UserRepository constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, UserEntity::class);
    }

    public function upgradePassword(UserInterface $user, string $newEncodedPassword): void
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', \get_class($user)));
        }

        $user->setPassword($newEncodedPassword);
        $this->_em->persist($user);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u, i')
            ->leftJoin('u.info', 'i')
            ->where('u.username = :username')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return \App\Entity\User::class === $class;
    }
}
```

```yaml
# config/packages/security.yaml

security:
    encoders:
        # ...
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            id: App\Repository\UserRepository
    firewalls:
        # ...
    access_control:
        # ...
```